# Bhuj seer's claim on menstruating women cooking for husbands

Tags: scripture, women

Swami Krushnaswarup of Swaminarayan Temple in Bhuj [claimed recently](https://indianexpress.com/article/india/bhuj-swami-krushnaswarup-dasji-menstruating-women-6274342/), that “menstruating women who cook food for their husbands will take birth as dogs in their next life while men consuming food prepared by women having periods will reborn as bullocks.”

This is the [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PY-58i7Cl1U) of his speech (in Gujarati)

Is there a scriptural basis for this assertion?